# android-ndk-r6-crystax-2 error: 'string' in namespace 'std' does not name a type

Tags: android, c++, compiler-errors, makefile, android-ndk

I have a project that builds fine with android-ndk-r4-crystax but when that I switched to android-ndk-r6-crystax I get the following error:

```
error: 'string' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
```

Anybody have any ideas on what the difference between crystax r4 and r6 that would cause this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed a #include  before all my other includes in all the files that reported this issue.